# exim "temporarily rejected after DATA"

Tags: exim, email-server

for two days now I always get the following message when receiving or trying to send mails in /exim4/mainlog

```
2011-12-09 15:05:41 1RZ153-00028W-AS DKIM: d=gmail.com s=gamma 
c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2011-12-09 15:05:42 1RZ153-00028W-AS H=mail-ee0-f53.google.com 
[74.125.xx.xx] F= <xxx@gmail.com> temporarily rejected after DATA
```

when trying to send mails. Receiving is also not working. Restarting exim didn't help...

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Regards

Comment: Almost certainly, the logs will give you a clue. Check `/var/log/mail.info` / `mail.log` / `mail/mail.info` or simply the syslog file for mail server log entries. The actual location will depend on your distribution and logging setup.

Comment: @syneticon-dj `Dec  9 14:16:09 nerdified exim[7717]: 2011-12-09 14:16:09 1RZ0J7-00020T-OL spam acl condition: warning - spamd connection to 127.0.0.1, port 783 failed: Connection refused
Dec  9 14:16:09 nerdified exim[7717]: exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above` This is all I get. I even stopped spam assassin. to see if this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permission problem with the [exim log file(s)](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_51.html) - exim is apparently set up to write own log files (and not log to syslog), but is disallowed to write them by filesystem permissions. It depends on the distribution and your configuration what files and directories are affected. Running

`exim -bd -d+all`

should help resolve the issue as it will throw debugging output to stdout and tell you what file could not be written. Make make sure that the file(s) in question is/are owned by the exim mail user (use ps auxw | egrep exim to check for the user name) and the directory exists and is owned by the exim mail user as well.

Comment: ok, i checked writing permissions and that is ok now panic log is now writable. But error still occurs on trying to mail. Also should I worry about this `14:52:56  8130 seeking password data for user "vmail": cache not available
14:52:56  8130 getpwnam() succeeded uid=107 gid=107
14:52:56  8130 seeking password data for user "www-data": cache not available
14:52:56  8130 getpwnam() succeeded uid=33 gid=33
14:52:56  8130 seeking password data for user "Debian-exim": cache not available
14:52:56  8130 getpwnam() succeeded uid=102 gid=102`

Comment: Check the exim log files for errors upon mail transmission again - they should contain something meaningful now. The `cache not abailable` messages should not be a problem.

Comment: exim log still contains `temporarily rejected after DATA`. After turning off ACL and Spamassasin `rejected RCPT` is the message. Could it be domains are not loaded correctly from MYSQL? We use vexim...

Comment: @syneticon-df after commenting out `acl_smtp_data = acl_check_content` it works again. Something in there seems to be wrong that all mails are  rejected

Comment: You should see something about the reason in exim's reject log. If you've set your [log level](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_51.html#SEC862) to 0, you might not get a sufficient amount of information logged for meaningful troubleshooting.

Comment: `Spam detection software, running on the system "mydomain.net", has identified this incoming email as possible spam` is the message I get for pretty much all mails if I turn it back on